# Entendendo como funciona a conversão de um Objeto para Json

Tags: c#, json

Tenho uma rota PUT que recebe um Json na variável "edicoes" e pelo que entendi, no C# acaba ficando como objeto.

Estava pesquisando uma forma de receber o arquivo corretamente e través de algumas pesquisas por ai, encontrei este código que não entendi muito bem mas funcionou e deu certo.

Queria realmente entender o que está acontecendo e porque foi preciso criar uma variável do tipo Usuario (minha classe)

`Usuario _edicoes = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(edicoes);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que ocorre nesse caso é que o C# é uma linguagem tipada e o seu objeto JSON é apenas uma string até que ocorra o processo de serialização, ou seja, converter esse texto JSON para um objeto tipado do C#.

O que o código:

```
Usuario _edicoes = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(edicoes);
```

Vai fazer é o equivalente a criar um novo objeto usando o `new`:

```
Usuario _edicoes = new Usuario();
```

Com a diferença que o método `DeserializeObject` do pacote `Newtondoft.Json` vai fazer o mapeamento das propriedades do objeto JSON para a sua classe definida no C# (Usuario), caso elas possuam o mesmo nome, exemplo:

JSON usuário:

```
{
  "nome": "Fulano",
  "sobrenome": "da Silva",
  "email": "fulano@gmail.com"
}
```

Classe usuário:

```
public class Usuario
{
   public string Nome { get; set; }
   public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Nesse caso, a deserialização ocorreria normalmente, já que os nomes das propriedades dos dois objetos coincidem. Um detalhe é que o pacote `Newtonsoft.Json` já aplica as convenções de nome e transforma as propriedades de [Camel Case](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/C-Sharp-coding-standards-and-naming-conventions/) do JSON para [Pascal Case](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/C-Sharp-coding-standards-and-naming-conventions/) no C#.